# MongoDB query filter array of objects and format return object

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "course1",
    "teams" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "1548600639880X5269760768997986",
            "title": "Team One",
            "members" : {
                "user1" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "1548601941683X14679065888073906",
            "title": "Team Two",
            "members" : {
                "user2" : true,
                "user3" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "1548602385020X41594057288000386",
            "title": "Team Three",
            "members" : {
                "user4" : true
            }
        }
    ],
    "updated_at" : "2019-01-27T15:31:43+00:00"
}
```

I'am trying to get the "team" of user2 with all user with value true. So the return object schould be something like this:

```
 {
     "key" : "1548601941683X14679065888073906",
     "title": "Team Two",
     "members" : {
         "user2" : true,
         "user3" : true
     }
  }
```

I tried a lot with db.getCollection('').find({}) but did not get the needed result.

Comment: What do you get? Did you get any result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [aggregation](http://%20https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). And below **aggregation** help you.

**db.getCollection('').find({})** can't be convert output into desire result.

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$teams" },
    { $match: {"teams.members.user2": true } },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$teams" }  } 
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That is exactly what i'am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('teams').find({
    "_id": "course1",
    "teams.members": { "user1": true }
})
```

gets me

```
{
    "_id" : "course1",
    "teams" : [ 
        {
            "key" : "1548600639880X5269760768997986",
            "title" : "Team One",
            "members" : {
                "user1" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "1548601941683X14679065888073906",
            "title" : "Team Two",
            "members" : {
                "user2" : true,
                "user3" : true
            }
        }, 
        {
            "key" : "1548602385020X41594057288000386",
            "title" : "Team Three",
            "members" : {
                "user4" : true
            }
        }
    ],
    "updated_at" : "2019-01-27T15:31:43+00:00"
}
```